# jQuery click but not the first-child

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a list

**HTML**

```
<ul class="choices">
    <li><a href="#" data-flag="en"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/United Kingdom.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-flag="de"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Germany.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-flag="es"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Spain.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-flag="fr"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/France.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-flag="it"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Italy.png" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to code in jQuery the ability to only allow an action on everything BUT the first child

I tried the following but to no avail

**jQuery**

```
$('.choices li:not(:first-child) a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Could someone maybe help me out with my code?

Comment: Are you sure about your HTML ? Because it works like a charm.

Comment: That should work, what is the problem?

Comment: check the console you are getting the "clicked" or not. Although there is no issues with the code. That should work great.

Comment: cant figure out whats wrong in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with code you can check in the given demo link. Make sure you have code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code...})`;

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/juPvn/1/)**

```
$('.choices li:not(:first-child) a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("clicked");
    alert("clicked");
});​
```

Comment: Creates a syntax error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Illegal_character